# WAMP server shows blank page on my wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp

Good day!
Today when I run my WordPress (index) site on localhost it only shows blank page. 
However, It doesn't show blank page on admin and still can access it smoothly. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you updated anything or installed a new plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try turning on debugging mode?

You do that in `wp-config.php`.

`Locate define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and set it to true.

Another thing I would try is to make some simple php file and test that if it is working. Something like:

```
<?php    
echo "test";    
?>
```

Alternatively, you can try checking & deactivating plugins. If its fixed or not. 
Read [How to Fix the WordPress White Screen of Death?](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death/) hopefully your issue will be solved.

good luck!

Comment: its so naive of me, but right now I discovered that in the wordpress root index.php file I sat "WP_USE_THEMES" to false and this resulted the WSOD :/

Answer (score 2):

try resetting the theme by running these commands in the console on your database

```
update wp_options set option_value = 'default' where option_name = 'template'
update wp_options set option_value = 'default' where option_name ='stylesheet'
```

After that try logging in using your wp-admin panel using your username and password and setting a different  theme of your choice.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score -1):

You're seeing a blank page because there's an error but you have error reporting turned off.

Turn on error reporting to find out where you need to be looking.

Comment: Could you tell me where to turn it on? Sorry if it's a newb question.